# Cancelling ongoing connectoin attempt in netty

Tags: sockets, kotlin, netty

`Bootstrap#connect()` returns a `CahnnelFuture` that eventually becomes un-cancellable. How do I cancel the ongoing connection attempt?

Code snippet for reference (kotlin):

```kotlin
    val f = Bootstrap()
            .group(NioEventLoopGroup(1))
            .channel(NioSocketChannel::class.java)
            .handler(object : ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                override fun initChannel(ch: SocketChannel?) {
                }
            })
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 10_000)
            .connect(InetSocketAddress("10.255.255.1", 80))
    f.addListener(ChannelFutureListener {
        println("success: ${it.isSuccess}")
    })
    val th = Thread {
        Thread.sleep(500)
        println("cancellable: ${f.isCancellable}")
        f.cancel(true)
    }.also { it.start() }
    f.sync()
    th.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the future become `non cancellable` you can't cancel the connection establishment anymore.

Comment: Are you saying there is no way to cancel a connect in netty? How come? On socket level cancelling connect is quite simple, for example by closing the socket.